# Converting data types on python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, type-conversion

|  | House Number | Street | First Name | Surname | Age | Relationship to Head of House | Marital Status | Gender | Occupation | Infirmity | Religion |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Smith Radial | Grace | Patel | 46 | Head | Widowed | Female | Petroleum engineer | None | Catholic |  |
| 1 | 1 | Smith Radial | Ian | Nixon | 24 | Lodger | Single | Male | Publishing rights manager | None | Christian |  |
| 2 | 2 | Smith Radial | Frederick | Read | 87 | Head | Divorced | Male | Retired TEFL teacher | None | Catholic |  |
| 3 | 3 | Smith Radial | Daniel | Adams | 58 | Head | Divorced | Male | Therapist, music | None | Catholic |  |
| 4 | 3 | Smith Radial | Matthew | Hall | 13 | Grandson | NaN | Male | Student | None | NaN |  |
| 5 | 3 | Smith Radial | Steven | Fletcher | 9 | Grandson | NaN | Male | Student | None | NaN |  |
| 6 | 4 | Smith Radial | Alison | Jenkins | 38 | Head | Single | Female | Physiotherapist | None | Catholic |  |
| 7 | 4 | Smith Radial | Kelly | Jenkins | 12 | Daughter | NaN | Female | Student | None | NaN |  |
| 8 | 5 | Smith Radial | Kim | Browne | 69 | Head | Married | Female | Retired Estate manager/land agent | None | Christian |  |
| 9 | 5 | Smith Radial | Oliver | Browne | 69 | Husband | Married | Male | Retired Merchandiser, retail | None | None |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I have a dataset which you can see up the side of the question. I want to convert all these datasets to integers and strings from objects.

```
df = pd.read_csv('user-data.csv')
df[['Street','Relationship to Head of House','Marital Status','Gender','Occupation','Infirmity','Religion']] = df[['Street','Relationship to Head of House','Marital Status','Gender','Occupation','Infirmity','Religion']].astype('str') 
df[['House Number','Age']] = df[['House Number','Age']].astype('int')
```

I tried two different ways but all the dataset was gone after that operations.

```
df = df['Street'].astype(str)
df = df['Relationship to Head of House'].astype(str)
df = df['Marital Status'].astype(str)
df = df['Gender'].astype(str)
df = df['Occupation'].astype(str)
df = df['Infirmity'].astype(str)
df = df['Religion'].astype(str)
df = df['Gender'].astype(str)
```

Could you help me to convert columns?
Thanks

I still got the same types as:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10610 entries, 0 to 10609
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                         --------------  ----- 
 0   House Number                   10610 non-null  int64 
 1   Street                         10610 non-null  object
 2   First Name                     10610 non-null  object
 3   Surname                        10610 non-null  object
 4   Age                            10610 non-null  object
 5   Relationship to Head of House  10610 non-null  object
 6   Marital Status                 7995 non-null   object
 7   Gender                         10610 non-null  object
 8   Occupation                     10610 non-null  object
 9   Infirmity                      10610 non-null  object
 10  Religion                       7928 non-null   object
dtypes: int64(1), object(10)
memory usage: 911.9+ KB
```

Object instead of int or string, could you help me to fix that?

Comment: String columns are of type object, this is normal

Comment: I taught it should be written string instead of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the df['Street']= df['Street'].astype(str) on the left side of the assignment

```
df['Street']= df['Street'].astype(str)
df['Relationship to Head of House'] = df['Relationship to Head of House'].astype(str)
df['Marital Status'] = df['Marital Status'].astype(str)
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].astype(str)
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].astype(str)
df['Infirmity'] = df['Infirmity'].astype(str)
df['Religion'] = df['Religion'].astype(str)
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].astype(str)
```

or

```
columns=df.columns
for column in columns:
    df[column]=df[column].astype(str)
```

or

```
in the pd.read_csv you can set the dtypes=[str,str,...] for each column
```

or

```
 numeric_df=df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')

 returns the a dataframe with non-numeric columns

 columns=numeric_df.columns
```

Comment: Can I do that for all the columns?

Comment: yes sir all columns

Comment: Can u check the new edited question?