# Replacement Values into the integer on dataset columns

Tags: python, string, dataframe, csv, replace

|  | House Number | Street | First Name | Surname | Age | Relationship to Head of House | Marital Status | Gender | Occupation | Infirmity | Religion |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Smith Radial | Grace | Patel | 46 | Head | Widowed | Female | Petroleum engineer | None | Catholic |  |
| 1 | 1 | Smith Radial | Ian | Nixon | 24 | Lodger | Single | Male | Publishing rights manager | None | Christian |  |
| 2 | 2 | Smith Radial | Frederick | Read | 87 | Head | Divorced | Male | Retired TEFL teacher | None | Catholic |  |
| 3 | 3 | Smith Radial | Daniel | Adams | 58 | Head | Divorced | Male | Therapist, music | None | Catholic |  |
| 4 | 3 | Smith Radial | Matthew | Hall | 13 | Grandson | NaN | Male | Student | None | NaN |  |
| 5 | 3 | Smith Radial | Steven | Fletcher | 9 | Grandson | NaN | Male | Student | None | NaN |  |
| 6 | 4 | Smith Radial | Alison | Jenkins | 38 | Head | Single | Female | Physiotherapist | None | Catholic |  |
| 7 | 4 | Smith Radial | Kelly | Jenkins | 12 | Daughter | NaN | Female | Student | None | NaN |  |
| 8 | 5 | Smith Radial | Kim | Browne | 69 | Head | Married | Female | Retired Estate manager/land agent | None | Christian |  |
| 9 | 5 | Smith Radial | Oliver | Browne | 69 | Husband | Married | Male | Retired Merchandiser, retail | None | None |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Hello,

I have a dataset that you can see below. When I tried to convert Age to int. I got that error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '43.54302670766108'

This means there is float data inside that data. I tried to replace '.' to '0' then tried to convert but I failed. Could you help me to do that?

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].replace('.','0')
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype('int')
```

I still got the same error. I think replace line is not working. Do you know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].replace('\..*$', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Or, more drastic:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].replace('^(?:.*\D.*)?$', '0', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: still got: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' –

Comment: @asli can you test the second command

Comment: Thanks that one worked. Could you also check my other question? It is similar to that one. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086440/converting-data-types-on-python-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manipulate the strings; you might first convert values to float then to int like:

```
df["Age"] = df["Age"].astype('float').astype('int')
```

Comment: I got "could not convert string to float: ''" error. They are object and sting as a first place